# Where in Mumbai Airport can I store luggage for a few hours?

Tags: india, bom, luggage-storage

I need to drop my check-in baggage (two big bags) for a few hours at Mumbai Airport. How can I safely and securely do this? What options do I have, if any? What costs should I expect? Are there any problems / issues / side-effects, that I have to take into account?

Comment: Google is your friend: http://www.csia.in/passenger/left-luggage.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your comment and if you wish to get some rep, then why don't you convert it into a full featured answer. However, I shall add, that I was asking to receive a bit more wider answer with details, that I may not find in simple Google search like, what to expect (i.e. long queues to the storage, long times of deposit and receive, overbooked and thus closed storage most times, no ability to pay by card etc. -- everything that may happen or often is happening at many luggage storages around the world).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chhatrapati Shivaji International Airport has a Baggage Storage Facility known as the **Left luggage**, which accepts bags for safe keeping up to 90 days.

**Charge:**

As per the [airport website](https://csmia.adaniairports.com/left-luggage.aspx), the minimum charge for safe keeping a **standard size bag is 200 INR per bag** and it is **270 INR for a larger bag** for up to **6 hours**. The charge increases with time.

**Location:**

From the official website, the storage facility is located at International Terminal 2, (Level - P-4, Zone-6). Left Luggage is better known as "Cloakroom".

**Queue:**

I could not find any info on queue at Left luggage but the Queue timings of Bombay airport are generally high than other airports as you can see in the customer [reviews](https://www.airlinequality.com/airport-reviews/mumbai-airport/). So expect and be prepared for a long queue.

You can fine more information including contact info at the [airport website](https://csmia.adaniairports.com/left-luggage.aspx).