# What's the most reliable way to travel between Phoenix MarketCity and Mumbai Airport?

Tags: india, airport-transfer, mumbai

It seems, that I'll have few hours of spare time between getting to Mumbai Airport and actually checking-in to my plane. Thus, I thought about visiting Phoenix MarketCity in between, after I [drop-off my luggage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/65337/15281) at the airport. Google Maps showed me, that both location are quite close to each other.

What is the safest way to travel between these two places? By "safest" I mean solution that can get me there an back on scheduled time, without too much delay, sticking in traffic jam etc. Or maybe, my entire idea is wrong, due to possible problems in getting to Phoenix MarketCity and back to airport?

My plane takes off very late in the night, so I'll be travelling to MarketCity [close to its closure](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/65364/15281). For this reason, I assume local buses are not an option around 00:00-01:00, right? Even though I saw bus stop at Google Maps directly next to Phoenix MarketCity, I assume, that there will be no bus service at all at that time or bus frequency will not grant safe traveling in terms of time (late bus or off-routed bus).

Comment: It is about 25Km from the airport and that is a long distance in Mumbai terms, can take more then an hour and a half in the evening rush hours (one way)

Comment: Olacab or uber is the probably the best option when you have luggage. Do keep extra time for traffic jams.

Comment: @ParminderSinghChahal Well... [Google Maps says](https://goo.gl/maps/4N8WnR5yfAJ2) that is is actually **six**, not 25 km. Are we talking about the same places?

Comment: @blvdeer As I stated in my question I **will not** have luggage (except for items purchased and brought back to the airport) so I don't necessary need a cab, if there are other options, I can consider.

Comment: @trejder yes it's 6 kms from the airport. My office is near the international airport and Phoenix Market City is on my home-office route. Coming out of terminal 2 and taking the Andheri-Kurla road will be the shortest route. But always keep buffer time because it's Mumbai and you never know about the traffic at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ola/uber to go around but if you are not able to find any then just hop into any taxi. If you end up going in a local taxi then only pay the amount which comes up in the cab meter, do not pay even a single extra penny.

During peak hours the traffic on Mumbai roads is crazy. I would suggest you to keep an hour and a half as buffer to have a relaxed visit to the mall.

Bus services in Mumbai shut by 12:00AM mostly so it will not be possible for you to get a bus at that time.

Comment: As I said, I'll be travelling around 11:00 PM. I hope there are no traffic jam at that hour in Mumbai? :>

Comment: Mostly there won't be.